# How to fetch nested variable in ansible template?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

How do I get the variable which is nested as below:

```
mongoservers:
- mongo_master: dev_01
  label: mongomaster dev01
  urls:
    - mongomaster01.dev.local.net
    - mongomaster02.dev.local.net
- mongo_master: dev_02
  label: mongomaster dev02
  urls:
    - mongomaster.dev03.local.net
    - mongomaster.dev04.local.net
```

I want to access urls in variable from the above yaml my condition is if `mongoservers.mongo_master` is `dev01` I want to grab all the urls belonging to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter and query your list of hashes with [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter). Read the [`jmespath` doc](http://jmespath.org/examples.html) to understand the query language

In the following example playbook, I'm using the following query:

```
[?mongo_master=='dev_01'].urls[]
```

which can be explained as

> For every element in the incoming list having a `mongo_master` element equal to `dev_01`, select the `urls` element inside it and finally flatten the list

Here is the complete example playbook:

```
---
- name: Filter list
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    mongoservers:
    - mongo_master: dev_01
      label: mongomaster dev01
      urls:
        - mongomaster01.dev.local.net
        - mongomaster02.dev.local.net
    - mongo_master: dev_02
      label: mongomaster dev02
      urls:
        - mongomaster.dev03.local.net
        - mongomaster.dev04.local.net

  tasks:
    - name: filter
      vars:
        query: >-
          [?mongo_master=='dev_01'].urls[]
      debug:
        msg: "{{ mongoservers | json_query(query) | list }}"
```

which gives:

```
PLAY [Filter list] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [filter] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Wednesday 25 September 2019  17:57:39 +0200 (0:00:00.039)       0:00:00.039 *** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "mongomaster01.dev.local.net",
        "mongomaster02.dev.local.net"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: can we do in template `{{ mongoservers | json_query([?mongo_master=='dev_01'].urls[]) | list }}` but getting syntax error

Comment: You need to quote the entire query: `{{ mongoservers | json_query("[?mongo_master=='dev_01'].urls[]") | list }}`. I put it in a var by habit to go over potential quoting and escaping hell issues.

Comment: Oh yeah! Life saver. Thanks mate